# PowerShell - Merge two variables into one

Tags: powershell, variables, environment-variables

I'm learning PowerShell so please forgive (what I'm sure is) a simple question.

I'm used to coding BATCH scripts and if I wanted to merge %USERDOMAIN% and %USERNAME% I would:

```
set zFullUsername=%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%
echo %zFullUsername%
```

How can I do the same in PowerShell?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you mean `$fullUserName = "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, you can access environment variables in a few different ways. The way I recommend is to use the `$env:VAR` variable to access them.

```
$user = $env:USERNAME
$domain = $env:USERDOMAIN

echo "$domain\$user"
```

> Note: `\` is not an escape character in the PowerShell parser, `` ` `` is.

Similarly to rendering the `echo` command (`echo` is an alias of `Write-Output` btw) you can create a username variable like so:

```
$fullUserName = "$domain\$user"
```

Or you can skip right to creating `$fullUserName` straight from the environment variables:

```
$fullUserName = "${env:USERDOMAIN}\${env:USERNAME}"
```

> Note: When variables have non-alphanumeric characters in them, the `${}` sequence tells PowerShell everything between the `${}` is part of the variable name to expand.
>
> It seems the `:` in `$env:VAR` is actually an exception to this rule, as
> `"Username: $env:USERNAME"` *does* render correctly. So the `${}` sequence above is optional.

---

To avoid confusion when trying to apply this answer in other areas, if you needed to insert the value of an object *property* or some other expression within a string itself, you would use a sub-expression within the string instead, which is the `$()` sequence:

```
$someVar = "Name: $($someObject.Name)"
```

> When using either `${}` or `$()`, whitespace is *not* allowed to pad the outer `{}` or `()`.

Comment: It now seems so obvious. I really appreciate the detail you provided.  Helps to understand the methodology rather than just copy and paste your answer.  I've used in within a command line of other code and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

On a supported Operating System, I wouldn't even bother with environment variables for this:

```
$zFullUsername = whoami
```

Then just access it as required:

```
$zFullUsername
```

Comment: As you stated, this works as long as 'whoami' is present on the PC.  I'll test in WinRE and WinPE if it is.  I guess you could use your answer by checking if 'whoami.exe' is present and the other answer as fallback.