# Set Variable assigning Import-csv value

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to assign import-csv value to a set variable under a loop
so i can work with the csv file on variable
$var1, $var2,$var3 like..

```
$i = 1
{
$result = Export-Csv -Path ".\$varname.csv" -NoTypeInformation 
New-Variable -Name "var$i" -Value "import-csv -Path .\$varname.csv"
Get-Variable -Name "var$i" -ValueOnly
$i++

}
```

Comment: [Don't use the `<verb>-Variable` cmdlets for dynamic variable names!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68830451/1701026)

Comment: `$Var = '.\fileOne.csv', '.\fileTwo.csv', '.\fileThree.csv'`. Now, `$Var[1]` contains `'.\fileTwo.csv'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is missing the actual problem you need help with or what is failing.
I see you're using `Export-Csv`, I would assume you meant to use `Import-Csv`.

If you want to store the content of a CSV and set that content to dynamically created variables, this is how you can do it:

```
$numberOfvariables = 5
$csv = Import-Csv path/to/csv.csv

0..$numberOfvariables | ForEach-Object {
    Set-Variable -Name var$_ -Value $csv
}
```

Note that, I'm using `Set-Variable` instead of `New-Variable`, both serve the same purpose in this example however if you re-run the script without removing the variables you would get the exception `A variable with name 'var' already exists.` using `New-Variable` unless you use the `-Force` switch.

Comment: Hi Santiago.. sorry for the confusion.. i am exporting a csv file with filename like file1,file2,file 3 in the loop from variable $varname.csv. During the loop i want to import each csv to a variable like $var1=file1, $var2 = file2, $var3 = file3 and so on.

Comment: Hi Santiago.. the key is to assign the ```$csv = Import-Csv path/to/csv.csv```.. much appreciated