# How to use string as variable in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a XAML gui in my powershell script.
I would like to know how I can use a string as a variable name ex. $grid.Name is WPFgrdCopy

This works:

```
$WPFgrdCopy.Background = "#FF212123"
```

This does not:

```
$grids = Get-Variable "wpfgrd*"
foreach($grid in $grids){
    $grid.Background = "#FF212123"
}
```

It doesn't because $grid is an object of the variable, how can I set attributes of $grid.Name (WPFgrdCopy)
I have also tried `Add-Member -InputObject $grid -NotePropertyMembers @{Background="#FF212123"} -Force`

Comment: `Get-Variable ... -ValueOnly`

Comment: It is generally a bad practice to use the [`<verb>-Variable` cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) for dynamic variable names! Use a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) instead, see also: [How do I automaticaly create and use variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68830451/1701026)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  objects of type [`System.Management.Automation.PSVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSVariable) that [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) returns have a read-write `.Value` property.

Therefore, one option is to access `$grid.Value` rather than `$grid`:

```bash
$grids = Get-Variable "wpfgrd*"
foreach($grid in $grids){
  $grid.Value.Background = "#FF212123"
}
```

However, as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, you can use `Get-Variable`'s `-ValueOnly` switch to directly return only the matching variables' *values*, which is sufficient here, given that your intent isn't to modify *what object* is stored in each variable but merely to modify a *property of* the *current* object:

```bash
$grids = Get-Variable "wpfgrd*" -ValueOnly
foreach($grid in $grids){
  $grid.Background = "#FF212123"
}
```

---

Taking a step back: As [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) points out, if you control the creation of the variables of interest, it **may be better to use the entries of a [hasthable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) instead of individual variables** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68830451/1701026) for more information.