# Array of reference to var in powershell

Tags: powershell, reference

Ok I guess this question has already been answered somewhere but I do not find it. So here is my few lines of codes

```
$a = 0
$b = 0
$c = 0

$array = @($a, $b, $c)

foreach ($var in $array) {
    $var = 3
}
Write-Host "$a : $b : $c"
```

What I try to do is loop into $array and modify a, b and c variables to get `3 : 3 : 3` ... I find something about `[ref]` but I am not sure I understood how to use it.

Comment: What is `$a`, `$b` and `$c`?

Comment: I edited my question so it is more understandable

Comment: You can't do that. Information about variables `$a`, `$b` and `$c` are not actually contained in the array

Comment: I do understand that but is there anyway that instead of storing a b and c value in the array I can store pointers or reference or something to access the variable ? @Mathias R. Jessen

Comment: I think this is where you heading to: [How do I automaticaly create and use variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68830451/1701026)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you can use the `[ref]` keyword, it will create an object with a "Value" property and that's what you have to manipulate to set the original variables.

```
$a = 1
$b = 2
$c = 3

$array = @(
    ([ref] $a),
    ([ref] $b),
    ([ref] $c)
)

foreach ($item in $array)
{
    $item.Value = 3
}

Write-Host "a: $a, b: $b, c: $c" # a: 3, b: 3, c: 3
```

You could also use the function `Get-Variable` to get variables:

```
$varA = Get-Variable -Name a
```

This way you can get more information about the variable like the name.

And if your variables have some kind of prefix you could get them all using a wildcard.

```
$variables = Get-Variable -Name my*
```

And you would get all variables that start with "my".

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to wrap the values in objects of a reference type (eg. a `PSObject`) and then assign to a property on said object:

```
$a = [pscustomobject]@{ Value = 0 }
$b = [pscustomobject]@{ Value = 0 }
$c = [pscustomobject]@{ Value = 0 }

$array = @($a, $b, $c)

foreach ($var in $array) {
    $var.Value = 3
}
Write-Host "$($a.Value) : $($b.Value) : $($c.Value)"
```

Since `$a` and `$array[0]` now both contain a *reference* to the same object, updates to properties on either will be reflected when accessed through the other